# discord.py two-part function name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using slash commands in my discord.py bot and... i want to make two-part function name, but I can't just do something like that:

```py
@cog_ext.cog_slash(
name="display config",
description="wyświetla config serwera.")
async def display_config(self, ctx: SlashContext):
```

because I have this:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py:416> exception=HTTPException('400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body\nIn name: String value did not match validation regex.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 492, in sync_all_commands
    raise ex
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 472, in sync_all_commands
    existing_cmds = await self.req.put_slash_commands(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: String value did not match validation regex.
```

I will be very grateful if someone knows how to name my function "display config" (with space)

(I am using discord_slash library for slash commands)

Answer (score 0):

the error came because of the name of command  where `display config` have space in between them which is invalid for command name to fix it remove space like this:

```py
@cog_ext.cog_slash(
name="display_config",
description="wyświetla config serwera.")
async def display_config(self, ctx: SlashContext):
```